# Show Qml-Window nicely after components are created

Tags: qml, qt5

i want to start my Qt Quick application in fullscreen mode on a very slow hardware. This means you can literally watch the UI getting constructed. Thats not nice.
I have already experimented with setting the visiblity= true in the OnCompletion of my window but it did not help.

I want to show my app nicely when every loading and layouting is completely done.

Thanks for any help

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a [blog post](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/04/27/fast-booting-qt-devices-part-2-optimizing-qt-application/) written a while back about optimising Qt Quick applications. Here are the do's and don'ts from that list:

> Do:
>
> - Design your application to start fast from the beginning. Think what is it that you want the user to see first.
> - Make startup animations to allow parallel loading.
> - Use chain loading. Run only as many loaders as you have cores in your CPU (e.g two cores: two loaders running at the same time).
> - First loader should not be asynchronous. Trigger the rest of the loaders.
> - Create QML plugins that are loaded when required.
> - Connect to back-end services only when required.
> - Let the QML plugins start up non-critical services and close those down when not required anymore.
> - Optimize your png / jpg images.
> - Optimize your 3d models by reducing the amount of vertices and removing parts that are not visible.
> - Optimise the 3D model loading by using glTF.
> - Use Qt Quick Controls 2.0. These are designed for embedded use and the creation times are a lot better than in Quick Controls 1.0 for
>     embedded use cases.
> - Limit the usage of clip & opacity.
> - Measure GPU limitations and take those into account when designing the UI.
> - Use Qt Quick Compiler to pre-compile the QML files.
> - Investigate if static linking is possible for your architecture.
> - Strive for declarative bindings instead of imperative signal handlers.
> - Keep property bindings simple. In general, keep QML code simple, fun and readable. Good performance follows.
> - When targeting multiple platforms and form factors, use file selectors instead of loaders and dynamic component instantiation.
>     Don’t be shy to “duplicate” simple QML code and use file selectors to
>     load tailored versions.
>
> Do not:
>
> - Go overboard with QML. Even if you use QML, you don’t need to do absolutely everything in QML.
> - Initialize everything in your main.cpp.
> - Create big singletons that contain all the require interfaces.
> - Create complex delegates for Listviews.
> - Use Qt Quick Controls 1.0 for embedded.
> - Clip should be avoided altogether if possible. (98% of the use cases this should be possible).
> - Fall into the common trap of overusing Loaders. Loader is great for lazy-loading larger things like application pages, but introduces too
>     much overhead for loading simple things. It’s not black magic that
>     speeds up anything and everything. It’s an extra item with an extra
>     QML context.
> - Overdo re-use. Maximum code re-use often leads to more bindings, more complexity, and less performance.

There's also a page about performance in the Qt docs:

[Performance Considerations And Suggestions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html)